# How to view the iframes/frames NAMES of window.length?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that has lots of frames.  I know that window.length will return the number of "child browsing contexts", i.e. frames and iframes, but how do I view a list of these and see the frame names?  What if I want, for instance, refer to one of them by name specifically, like `window.parent.frames["foo"]`.. without just knowing I have to enter 'foo', how can I see the list of frame names?  Every time I drill down into the window object in dev tools or something, then expand the 'frame' object, I just seems to get the same 'window' object again and not a list of frames... and if I keep drilling down into 'frames' I recursively go nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend of what browser you are using.

For instance if you use Firefox there is a button in the developer tool that can point at a specific iframe within a document.

[image]
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Working_with_iframes

---

For Chrome there is the same kind of feature

[image]

See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

---

**In javascript:**

You can access window and document of a child frame if the iframe is **on the same domain**, else you'll got a CORS error

```
window.frames["frame_name"].contentWindow
```

if the HTML were:

```
<frame name="frame_name">...</frame>
```

To have the list of iframes names:

```
for (var i=0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
   console.log(window.frames[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  For my project, which uses framesets and frames, in Chrome devtools I do see that select in the console. There is also Sources tab > Network tab on the left that shows each frame (with each frame being a dir with resources in the dir)  But I'm SURPRISED that there isn't a way to see this info in the window object in javascript.. especially since you can do `window.parent.frames["foo"]` ...

Comment: Thanks.. that's helpful.  Still surprises me you can't just get at all this easily from the window object.

Comment: Probably because window.frames is a pseudo-array see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames and read this thread for more details: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/VijG80aFnU8

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the frames and view/store their names:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.parent.frames.length; i++) { 
  console.log(window.parent.frames[i].name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. that's helpful.  Still surprises me you can't just get at all this easily from the window object.